# t-sql: convert varchar to xml

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xml-parsing

I have some valid and invalid xml values stored in a varchar column.

I'd like to cast the valid xml values to the actual xml data type and invalid to nulls.

What's a good way to do this ?

Something like:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN dbo.isValidXML(xml_data) THEN CAST(xml_data as XML)
    ELSE null 
END
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1)

Comment: Can you not **run a process during the loading** of this data to reject invalid XML, otherwise you are running this query via a function each time you use this select statement, which is not ideal for performance.

Comment: yes, I know.   This is how I try to identify invalid XML values  before loading it.

Comment: See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43740683/3692256

Answer (score 9):

In response solely to this:

> Yes, but the beef of my question is how do I check is XML is valid in
>   the first place?

Is your XML invalid in the sense that you'll get a break like the second line below this:

```
SELECT CAST('<xml>Yep this is xml</xml>' AS XML)
SELECT CAST('<xml>Nope, not xml</x' AS XML)
```

One solution I see is a row-by-row approach, where you try and `CAST` a row as `XML`, and if it casts as `XML` successfully insert the valid row into a table with valid `XML` values, if it won't cast correctly, the value isn't inserted.  [See this thread for examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381864/ms-sql-server-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-if-a-given-string-is-a-valid-xm).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other thread, where it suggested to manually parse for the token in question.  That's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `sp_xml_preparedocument` -

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @XML NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @XML = '<t>test</'

DECLARE @hDoc INT

BEGIN TRY

     EXEC sys.sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML 
     SELECT '"' + @XML + '" is valid'
     EXEC sys.sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
     SELECT '"' + @XML + '" is invalid'     
END CATCH

SELECT @XML = '<t>test</t>'

BEGIN TRY

     EXEC sys.sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML 
     SELECT '"' + @XML + '" is valid'
     EXEC sys.sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
     SELECT '"' + @XML + '" is invalid'     
END CATCH
```

Output -

```
-------------------------
"<t>test</" is invalid

-------------------------
"<t>test</t>" is valid
```

Comment: Exceptional! Thank you so much for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the **XML** whether valid or invalid, you could have a **flag** on the table like `IsValid (bit)`.  The loading process could then do a one off check on this data to check if the XML is valid and set the flag based on the result.  This way you can get the valid XML by using the query:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN IsValid = 1 THEN CAST(xml_data as XML)
    ELSE null 
END
```

If you don't need to keep invalid XML, then just reject it during the loading, setting the field to `NULL`, so the query would look like:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN xml_data IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(xml_data as XML)
    ELSE null 
END
```

Both ways will give better performance that passing through a `SQL function` for **each query**.

Comment: Yes, but the beef of my question is how do I check is XML is valid in the first place ?

Comment: `I have some valid and invalid xml values stored in a varchar column.` - is this storage step under your control? or are you querying against a pre-populated table?

Comment: a prepopulated table.   Basically, I  need a way to check XML string validity using t-sql.