# How to test if field is XML in xpath query?

Tags: sql-server, xpath

I query an image field to parse out the Lot number but I cannot be guaranteed that the image field will be XML.  I am querying using embedded SQL.  Not a stored proc.

How can I test if the field is XML and if not, get out gracefully?
i.e. NullIf (not XML) or equivalent.

```
DECLARE @x xml
SET @x =  (SELECT [image]
  FROM [QM].[dbo].[ticket]
  where ticket_id = :ticketID)
SELECT @x.query('(/*:NewDataSet/*:tickets/*:lot/text())[1]')as LotNo
```

Comment: what data type is the image column

Comment: Image is a Text data type.

Comment: @springer_rider See answers to a similar question herel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381864/ms-sql-server-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-if-a-given-string-is-a-valid-xm

Answer (score 0):

I actually run the query above.  If it fails due to not being proper XML, I set the Lot No to '';